# MonoTouch Linking Native References in Debug only

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, static-linking, native-code

I have a MonoTouch project where I want to include a reference to some native ios libraries that are only used for testing & debugging. I do not  need these refereces to be compiled into the release build.

I've tried editing the .csproj file to have a Condition for the ItemGroup that links in the Native References, but they seem to be ignored.

```
 <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
<NativeReference Include="some path">
  <IsCxx>false</IsCxx>
  <Kind>Static</Kind>
</NativeReference>
```

I suppose there could be some way using the Additional mtouch arguments option in the project Options window. I am unsure though.

Does anyone know how I can link a native reference for a specific build configuration only in MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 3):

MonoDevelop let you provide different **Addtional mtouch arguments** for every configuration it defines for your project. In general it means each of the four: `[Debug|Release]|iPhone[Simulator]` could use different settings.

If you're manually adding a static library then it's easy to add (or remove) it from a specific target.

However if you're using bindings made with the new `[LinkWith]` support then those additional arguments are *automagically* made for you. There could be ways to hack around this (e.g. changing the **Build Action**) but I did not try them out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using the new bindings so the additional arguments are made for me. If I look at the output of gcc_flags then I can see that the libs are being linked. Nothing I have tried adding to Additional mtouch arguments has been able to change that.

Comment: You should fill an *enhancement* bug report on MonoDevelop to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com - it might be already be possible (but not easy to discover ;-) or it should be made possible in the future (it's a very good and valid scenario).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I suppose for now I can just create 2 separate projects: one for release, one for debug builds. In the debug project, I can simply link all files from the other project, and add the native references there. Seems almost similar to creating duplicate targets using XCode.